# (Why) is the category of $k$-linear operads not abelian?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, operads

For $k$ a field, a $k$-linear operad is defined to be a symmetric operad in the category of $\mathbb{Z}$-graded $k$-vector spaces (that is, a symmetric sequence of $k$-vector spaces such that certain conditions are satisfied). Morphisms between $k$-linear operads are sequences of $k$-linear equivariant maps that respect the operadic composition and preserve the operadic units.

The category $\mathsf{Oper}_k$ of $k$-linear operads can equivalently be defined as the category of monoids and monoid morphisms in the monoidal category $([\mathbb{P}^{op},\mathsf{vect}_k^{\mathbb{Z}}],\circ)$ of functors $\mathbb{P}^{op}\rightarrow \mathsf{vect}_k^{\mathbb{Z}}$. Here $\circ$ denotes the subsitution/composition product. Clearly the functor category $[\mathbb{P}^{op}, \mathsf{vect}_k^{\mathbb{Z}}]$ is abelian, since the category of $k$-vector spaces $\mathsf{vect}_k^{\mathbb{Z}}$ is.

- I am trying to disprove that also $\mathsf{Oper}_k$ is abelian. But where does abelianness go wrong?

$\mathsf{Oper}_k$ is pre-additive. Finite coproducts exist. (And products?) Every morphism has a kernel and cokernel. Is every monomorphism normal, every epimorphism conormal? Quick ways to see this?

Comment: Are you sure the category is preadditive? Operads concentrated in degree one would be unital graded algebras. There are unital algebras which admit no morphisms to one another, so the hom set can't be an abelian group.